# Can't consume entire memory

Tags: java, heap-memory

I am trying to write a program which should consume memory of a specific size. An issue I am wondering of is that I am getting `outOfMemory` exception when there is actually a free space in the heap.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Vector;
import java.lang.*;

public class MemoryEater1 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        long mb = Long.valueOf(args[0]);
        Vector v = new Vector();
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        while (true) {
            if (v.size() > 0) {
                if (((long) v.size())*100 <  mb) {
                    System.out.println("total memory: " + rt.totalMemory()/1024/1024);
                    System.out.println("max memory: " + rt.maxMemory()/1024/1024);
                    System.out.println("free memory: " + rt.freeMemory()/1024/1024);                        
                    System.out.println("Trying to add 100 mb");                 
                    //100mb
                    byte b[] = new byte[104857600];
                    v.add(b);
                }
            } else {
                //100mb
                byte b[] = new byte[104857600];
                v.add(b);
                System.out.println("Added 100 mb");             
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

The command to start it:

```
 java -Xmx4096m MemoryEater1 3000
```

And the output:

```
total memory: 2867
max memory: 3641
free memory: 59
Trying to add 100 mb
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at MemoryEater1.main(MemoryEater1.java:18)
```

Well the difference between max memory and total memory is 774mb, which should be enough to consume 100mb more, but still there is the error, and even the machine resources are sufficient enough:

```
[user@machine ~]$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         15950       3447      12502          0        210       2389
-/+ buffers/cache:        847      15102
Swap:         4031 1759218603       8941
```

Why can that be?

Comment: Did you notice free memory is lower than 100 Mb?

Comment: When you allocate large arrays, you always run into the risk of the JVM being unable to find a huge contiguous block for you, even when there's supposed to be room left.

Comment: @Stephan That would only be relevant if `totalMemory` was already expanded to `maxMemory`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, but is `totalMemory` is growing on demand or from time to time? Meaning that the allocation failed because the memory didn't had the time to grow (just an idea) before the new allocation of array

Comment: @AxelH No, that's not how things work. The JVM will make every effort to satisfy an allocation request.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, Ok thanks for the info. This leave only the "fragmentation" problem. So reducing the array on each exceptin will give more chance to use more space.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik except for defragmentating to create a contiguous block apperently.

Comment: @BobBrinks Except for everything it doesn't otherwise do. The point is that whatever technique it _does_ perform, it won't fail before trying to apply it.

Comment: Does your machine have enough free memory to accommodate this?  It could be that the JVM is willing based on the configuration but when it tries to increase the heap, the OS says it's not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's fragmentation as you only have one thread allocating memory and not reclaiming anything.

It's your particular garbage collector to blame, they manage memory differently resulting in more or less being unavailable for your app. You can find out which one is used by analyzing the output of `java -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags`).

You can try to use G1 which manages memory differently.

```
java -Xmx4096m -XX:+UseG1GC MemoryEater1 3000
```

Or play with generation sizes e.g. `-XX:NewSize` and so on.

For more information read up [VM options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) and anything on garbage collector algorithms e.g. [GC tuning]

Here's a quick illustration how splitting memory for different generations can make it unavailable (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html).
[image: Memory layout]

Comment: It seems like he has none of the big arrays going out of scope and therefore none eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: His code is design to keep everything out of hand of the GC.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set the JVM flags for an amount of memory greater than the physical memory on your machine.  With the information given so far, it seem most likely that you lack the physical memory to allocate this array.  In other words, the JVM requests more memory from the OS and the OS says there's none to give.

Another possibility is the memory fragmentation issue noted in the comments to your question.  I think that less likely, however, in this case because of the structure of your program.  I don't think it can be ruled out though.